# How to fix select checkbox with keyboard on jquery.steps.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an accessibility problem in jQuery.steps.js plugin.
For some reason is blocking me to select a checkbox with the space bar, on the official website you can see the Advanced Form demo on the last step (step 4) they have a checkbox and you can see that it is not possible to select it with the keyboard.

http://www.jquery-steps.com/examples#advanced-form

Have you had this problem? how to solve it?

Comment: This plugin is 4 years old, I think you will run into many more problems along the way if you use this plugin.
edit: Why not use just a validation plugin and program the step functionally yourself, shouldn't be too hard (allow clicking of button if validation is good)

Comment: that is the power of open source, not to do everything yourself. which others brand new plugins do you recommend me to do this steps? Do you know any other out there? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I googled jquery validation and you could use this for the validation part: 
https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation (last commit was 12 days ago) I never used this plugin, but it seems ok. Feel free to dig around a bit more and find a better plugin if you are not fully satisfied with it.

The "steps" are just simple css to show/hide stuff based on what elements are filled out. You don't need any plugin for this, you can do some transitioning effects with base jQuery (or CSS3). The important thing is to validate the steps (with plugin mentioned above) and if validation is true, you enable the button for the next step.

Comment: Thank you @cloned, The only reason I am using this plugin is that they offer accessibility support out of the box.

Comment: but it seems like you have problems with the accessibility? Default browser elements are accessible out of the box, you won't need any plugin for this. The only thing you need to watch out if any javascript modifies your input elements / checkboxes / whatever, then you have to check if they are still accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem: no selection of checkboxes within steps-container.

my solution:
i added the line:
    enableKeyNavigation: false, 
(default is true)
means: Enables keyboard navigation if true (arrow left and arrow right).

after this change I could select checkboxes with space-key.

Comment: But you lost accessibility. the main idea of using that plugin is because comes with accessibility out of the box. Obviously, if accessibility is not your concern then your fix is awesome, thanks for sharing it.